# Svg viewbox and preserveAspectRatio is not doing like expected

Tags: svg, viewbox

I am viewing the following svg http://pastebin.com/pNdNEQ6z in my Firefox and chome.

Can someone tell me why the two graphs are somewhere in der middle of y an not starting at the top? If you change the viewbox to "0 200 650 800" everything is fine. why 200? I have played with preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" but this is not doing anything.

At the end of the day I want to display both charts completely visible starting at the top? And I would like to understand why it is not doing so right now :-)

Comment: sorry, I really have tried a lot but I could not see the typo ... shame on me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you had a typo on your first embedded `<svg>` element (you had `hight="400"` instead of `height="400"`) and were not using a `…YMin` alignment on the outer.

Fixed, it looks like this:

```xml
<svg … preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
  <svg … height="400">
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WAVZj/

Comment: omg what a shame ... sorry, I really have tried a lot but I could not see the typo.